# What is the best way to drain my patio?

Tags: drain, patio

Here is what the lowest corner of my patio looks like in heavy rain.
My plan is to remove some of the cement bricks in that corner and to create some sort of drain -not sure if I should connect it to a dry well or use a sort of french drain to drain the water from that corner. 
I would not prefer any of the above since I have a design in mind for my garden that counts on that corner not being traversed above ground by any visible mark , as a matter of fact there would be a dwarf japanese maple there so I do not plan to expose his roots to water that is freezing in the soil, I guess a deeper dry well is the only viable alternative...do you have any other ideas ?
[image]

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Comment: I am at the point where I have to dig either a dry well or a trench for a french drain 
The area gets fooded as you see it but the water disappears quickly after the rain is gone so I am not in a rush to fix that as I have more pressing issues
That is why this does not have an answer. The way am going to do it is to install a drain in the corner and connect that under the concrete edging to either a dry well (less probable) or a french drain completely buried in the ground

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the bricks sitting on a bed of rock or sand.
 I would pull them up just beyond the point they go under water and add some fresh sand pack it and the problem is fixed.
I say this because their is a distinct drop off. I have seen this with pavers many times at the border or a high traffic area. The edges the base tends to migrate out causing your problem exactly. Give that a try before a French drain system because your yard from what little I can see in the photo looks flat. A dry well only works as long as it can accept the water since you have standing water a dry well may not provide acceptable results.

Comment: nope, the patio is designed to drain that way because that is the only way away from the house and its walls, That is the SE corner, NW and SW corner are adjacent to the house which meant NE corner is in the middle of the house and I could not drain there, so the patio is like a rectangle that is sloped fro all the other corners toward the corner you see. I do no intend to change that, it so by intent not by accident, It is just unfinished business, that patio killed me in my first year in this house, I think I posted about it around here in 2014

Comment: Sorry then I guess it was a fail on the design , since you have standing water a French drain would be the only way to get rid of the water a dry well will do the same thing once filled up with water unless it is large enough to leach the water but you mentioned you did not want any difference in the looks.

Comment: not a failed desing but unfinished work. In the mean time the landscaping design came into equation, hence my question, what other options are there?